# Arduino frequency counter Issue

Tags: arduino, counter, frequency, led

I am successfully using this great Arduino frequency library: [Arduino frequency counter](http://interface.khm.de/index.php/lab/experiments/arduino-frequency-counter-library/).

But there is one issue with my LEDs. They are working if I give them the value "HIGH" or "255". But however they are not working with a lower value. I have tested the LEDs in another sketch. So they are correctly wired and are working fine, also the Arduino. It seems to be a problem with the "FreqCounter::start(100);" line. If I remove it, the lower values are working, but of course the frequency counter is not...

How can I fix this problem?

Here's the code:

```
#include <FreqCounter.h>

unsigned long frq;

/*** OUTPUT LED ***/
int ledGreen = 9;
int ledYellow = 10;
int ledRed = 11;

void setup() {
  pinMode(ledGreen, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledYellow, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledRed, OUTPUT);

  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Frequency Counter");
}

void loop() {

  /*** WRITE ***/
  analogWrite(ledGreen, 255);
  analogWrite(ledYellow, 100);
  analogWrite(ledRed, 10);

  /*** FREQUENCY COUNTER ***/
  FreqCounter::f_comp = 10; // Calibration value / calibrate with a professional frequency counter
  FreqCounter::start(100);  // 100 ms gate time

  while (FreqCounter::f_ready == 0){
    frq = FreqCounter::f_freq;
  }
}
```

Comment: I received a hint ... the problem is that the library I use, disables the hardware timer during the gate time. So during this time the PWMS are out of order!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation this library repurposes TIMER1 for counting the frequency. However PWM for pins 9 and 10 requires TIMER1 with the default setup.

Comment: yes thats right ... I received a sketch in which no timer is in use. It uses instead an interrupt. Heres the threat: [Frequency Counter Sketch](http://forum.arduino.cc//index.php?topic=64219.30)